# No color in FMX TFont, why?

Tags: firemonkey

In XE6 I noticed that the Firemonkey TFont class has no way to specify the font's color whereas the Vcl.TFont does. Does anyone know the reason for this?

FMX.TFont only has properties for Family, Size and Style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can only speculate on the reason. The GDI+ DrawString function uses a Brush (=Fill in FireMonkey) for filling the string. It looks like they just decided to do it in a similar way. The name FillText also suggests some association with the Fill.

```
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Aqua;
  Canvas.FillText(RectF(0, 0, 100, 100), 'test', False, 1.0, [], TTextAlign.Center);
```

Comment: I see. Note that FillText appears to be deprecated in at least XE6, instead use RenderLayout from TTextLayout.